# Add a QGraphicsView to a QGraphicsWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to display a QGraphicsView inside a QGraphicsWidget, but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I want to achieve, where the QGraphicsWidgets are all added to a QGraphicsScene, and each widget has their own QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView.
[image]
The large box represents the main view, and the smaller boxes represent widgets, each with their own view and scenes.

My current implementation doesn't work, due to the following error:

> TypeError: QGraphicsLinearLayout.addItem(QGraphicsLayoutItem):
>   argument 1 has unexpected type 'QGraphicsView'

My implemetation in a subclass of the `QGraphicsWidget`:

```
self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
self.view.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

self.setLayout(QtGui.QGraphicsLinearLayout(Qt.Vertical))
self.layout().addItem(self.view)
```

I've tried to implement this with a QGraphicsLayoutItem, but I couldn't find anywhere to stick the QGraphicsView in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The function `QGraphicsLinearLayout.addItem` expects a `QGraphicsWidget` parameter and you are passing a normal `QWidget` (`QGraphicsView`).

You can use the class `QGraphicsProxyWidget` which is specially designed for wrapping `QWidget` into `QGraphicsWidget`.

I do not have Qt + Python on hands but I think it should look as follows:

```
proxy = parentView.addWidget(nestedView) # QWidget -> QGraphicsWidget
self.layout().addItem(proxy)
```